# How to scale axes independently at runtime on an NSButton

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsimage, objective-c-runtime, nsbutton

In Interface Builder, you can select how you want a button's image to be scaled, choosing either Axes Independent, Proportionally Down, etc. for the "Scaling" drop-down. How can I access or change this attribute of the NSButton at runtime?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to set that by using [the button’s cell](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButtonCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSButton *someButton;

NSButtonCell *someButtonCell = [someButton cell];
[someButtonCell setImageScaling:NSImageScaleAxesIndependently];
```

For the list of image scaling options, see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSImageScaling).